# Ignoring all but the (multi-line) results of the last query sent to a program

Tags: bash

I have an executable that accepts queries from stdin and responds to them, reading until EOF. Additionally I have an input file and a special command, let's call those `EXEC`, `FILE` and `CMD` respectively.

What I need to do is:

- Pass `FILE` to `EXEC` as input.
- Disregard all the output corresponding to commands read from `FILE` (`/dev/null/`).
- Pass `CMD` as the last command.
- Fetch output for the last command and save it in a variable.

`EXEC`'s output can be multiline for each query.

I know how to pass `FILE + CMD` into the `EXEC`:

```
echo ${CMD} | cat ${FILE} - | ${EXEC}
```

but I have no idea how to fetch only output resulting from `CMD`.
Is there a magical one-liner that does this?

After looking around I've found the following partial solution:

```
mkfifo mypipe

(tail -f mypipe) | ${EXEC} &

cat ${FILE} | while read line; do
    echo ${line} > mypipe
done

echo ${CMD} > mypipe
```

This allows me to redirect my input, but now the output gets printed to screen. I want to ignore all the output produced by `EXEC` in the `while` loop and get only what it prints for the last line.

I tried what first came into my mind, which is:

```
(tail -f mypipe) | ${EXEC} > somefile &
```

But it didn't work, the file was empty.

Comment: As an aside, putting a command fragment in a variable -- as with `${EXEC}` -- is a [really unfortunate practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). If you mean to just have a placeholder, maybe call it `my-command` (or, even better, include a shell function that can stand in for that command to make your code demonstrable/executable, as per the "verifiable" criteria in [mcve])?

Comment: EXEC is just path to an executable file.

Comment: How can you tell when the end of the output starts? Is there a sigil you can look for?

Comment: What do you mean by "end of the output"?

Comment: ...if you **really** want to rely on setting a flag when the input source changes, you'll need to do some IPC-like magic. Doable, but a bit race-prone. Anyhow, if it's **really** what you want to do (and I advise against it, vs trying to generate a pattern you can match in the output), it'd be a bit easier if you're running a bash release new enough to expose the PID of a process substitution. What's the oldest shell release this needs to work with?

Comment: By "end of the output", I was referring to the part you actually want to capture.

Comment: I can't distinguish it from the rest of the output by just looking at the file, I have to actually do something between the `while` and the `CMD` call.

Comment: If I could write the `EXEC`'s output into a file and for example add a sigil between the calls, or even clear the file it'd be enough.

Comment: Adding a sigil is, as I said, racey, *unless* it's your `"$EXEC"` program doing it itself -- you can't be sure all the content generated as output from the old commands has been flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is race-prone -- I'd suggest putting in a delay after the `kill`, or using an explicit sigil to determine when it's been received. That said:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# route FD 4 to your output routine
exec 4> >(
  output=; trap 'output=1' USR1
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $output ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
); out_pid=$!

# Capture the PID for the process substitution above; note that this requires a very
# new version of bash (4.4?)
[[ $out_pid ]] || { echo "ERROR: Your bash version is too old" >&2; exit 1; }

# Run your program in another process substitution, and close the parent's handle on FD 4
exec 3> >("$EXEC" >&4)  4>&-

# cat your file to FD 3...
cat "$file" >&3

# UGLY HACK: Wait to let your program finish flushing output from those commands
sleep 0.1

# notify the subshell writing output to disk that the ignored input is done...
kill -USR1 "$out_pid"

# UGLY HACK: Wait to let the subprocess actually receive the signal and set output=1
sleep 0.1

# ...and then write the command for which you actually want content logged.
echo "command" >&3
```

In validating this answer, I'm doing the following:

```
EXEC=stub_function
stub_function() {
  local count line
  count=0
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    (( ++count ))
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$count" "$line"
  done
}

cat >file <<EOF
do-not-log-my-output-1
do-not-log-my-output-2
do-not-log-my-output-3
EOF
file=file

export -f stub_function
export file EXEC
```

Output is only:

```
4: command
```

Comment: The UGLY HACK is indeed ugly, so I'm leaving this question open in case someone comes up with a cleaner solution. Thank you nonetheless, I'll use this if all else fails.

Comment: *nod*. Do you have `flock` installed? Could use it to ensure that the signal is received, though even that won't let you be certain that the `EXEC` program is actually done flushing output -- that latter certainty isn't possible at all unless you can actually modify that program.

Comment: ...so, I would still suggest looking at your `EXEC` program, and whether you can feed it a command which has no behavior *other than* giving it expected/anticipated output it can use as a sigil to use to start recording. It's rare to have a database that can't do something like `SELECT 'my-constant-here'`, a command line with no `echo 'my-constant-here'` equivalent, etc. Otherwise, we can get rid of the 2nd UGLY HACK delay, but not the first one.

Comment: I can't really change the interface of the `EXEC`. It's basically an interpreter that takes a command like, let's say `2+2` and responds with a line `4` (that's just to state the problem, not what queries it actually does).
Is there no way to "simulate a user" in bash? Someone who sits in front of the terminal, types stuff, analyzes the output and types more stuff?

Comment: Plenty of ways to do that, but think about what your simulated user needs to do -- the "analyzes the output" step involves figuring out when output is done being written. That means actual temporal analysis of "how much delay happened since the last line?". Humans do that so naturally you didn't even think about it as an explicit step, but if you want code to do something like that, it needs to be written.

Comment: ...if you're looking for something with that capability built-in, bash may not be the best language -- if you're handy with TCL, see [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), or with Python, [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). For a shell-centric alternative, consider [EmPTY](http://empty.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Alternately -- does your program write a prompt when it's done with output from the last command? How does a user who's operating it at a console know when it's finished writing the output from the last command and ready for a new one? Just time delay? Looking for a prompt? Looking for an end-of-output sigil? Something else?

Comment: It calculates things first, then spits the output in one batch ending with a newline. No prompts unfortunately.

Comment: "Ending in a newline" meaning an *extra* newline / empty line, or just a newline like any other? If the latter, then it sounds like you really are asking for a decision being made temporally / by looking at amount of delay, which is to say that we're in a pretty hacky space by necessity. (If you have any influence with the folks who write this program, you might ask them to put a NUL after each batch of output -- a compliant terminal will ignore a NUL, but it makes it easy for machine parsing to find the point in question).

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe it into a sed:

```
var=$(YOUR COMMAND | sed '$!d')
```

This will put only the last line into the variable

Comment: As I mentioned, the output for the last query can be multiline and I need all of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your proram EXEC does something special (open connection or remember state). When that is not the case, you can use

```
${EXEC} < ${FILE} > /dev/null
myvar=$(echo ${CMD} | ${EXEC})
```

Or with normal commands:

```
# Do not use (printf "==%s==\n" 1 2 3 ;  printf "oo%soo\n" 4 5 6) | cat
 printf "==%s==\n" 1 2 3 | cat > /dev/null
 myvar=$(printf "oo%soo\n" 4 5 6 | cat)
```

When you need to give all input to one process, perhaps you can think of a marker that you can filter on:

```
(printf "==%s==\n" 1 2 3 ;  printf "%s\n" "marker"; printf "oo%soo\n" 4 5 6) | cat | sed '1,/marker/ d'
```

You should examine your EXEC what could be used. When it is running SQL, you might use something like

```
(cat ${FILE}; echo 'select "DamonMarker" from dual;' ; echo ${CMD} ) |
   ${EXEC} | sed '1,/DamonMarker/ d'
```

and write this in a var with

```
myvar=$( (cat ${FILE}; echo 'select "DamonMarker" from dual;' ; echo ${CMD} ) |
       ${EXEC} | sed '1,/DamonMarker/ d' )
```

Comment: It remembers a state.

Comment: And do you have the possibility to force an outout string at the end of FILE ?